# Can I access ionic Storage from an E2E test with protractor

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, jasmine, protractor

I want to e2e test a login process. After Login some information about the user will be stored in ionic storage. I have a pageObject that logs a user in by using browser commands from protractor and everything works fine.

The only part that is missing is comparing the user data from storage to the expected value.
And i have no clue how to do that.

```
constructor(private storageService:StorageService, username: string, password: string,)
```

this would be the constructor for the login pageObject but since i cant create a new storageService object in my Login.spec file it produces an error

The question i want to answer is: is the right data written into ionic storage after login (it is not written to local or session storage)

Are there any best practices for that scenario?

Comment: so your question is how to read data from the local and session storage?

Comment: no from the ionic storage but from within my e2e test